# View series of requests in Postman when getting token via OAUTH 2

Tags: oauth-2.0, request, postman, okta-api

I am obtaining access token in postman by going to `Authorization` tab and clicking on `Get New Access Token`. Below window pops up:

[image]

Now after clicking on `Request Token`, an OKTA window pops up where I enter username and password and am able to obtain the access token. Now I want to see all the requests postman makes in the background. I mean which URL it hits, which query parameters it uses and what all goes in the request header.

I tried to open the console, but it only shows the request that postman made after I entered my username and password on the OKTA login page. And in that request it uses `authorization code`, which it must have received by making some other request first. Can anyone please help me view all the requests and responses that happen in the background? Finally I am able to see the access token in one of the postman windows, but how can I view the actual response (raw/json) containing this token?

Last question: I use redirect uri(or callback url) as `https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback`, so how can I view the request that was made to this URI (by OKTA)?

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you manage to find a solution @shiva.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't. @the_big_blackbox

Comment: I came across this tool https://www.telerik.com/fiddler after I asked the question. It seems quite useful for viewing api request and responses made by your machine.